# CBV Django Form View set data for ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using the Django Form View and I want to enter custom choices per user to my `Choicefield`.

How can I do this?

Can I use maybe the `get_initial` function?
Can I overwrite the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to change certain things about a form such as the label text, adding required fields or filtering a list of choices etc. I follow a pattern where I use a ModelForm and add a few utility methods to it which contain my overriding code (this helps keep `__init__` tidy). These methods are then called from `__init__` to override the defaults.

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('country', 'contact_phone', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.set_querysets()
        self.set_labels()
        self.set_required_values()
        self.set_initial_values()

    def set_querysets(self):
        """Filter ChoiceFields here."""
        # only show active countries in the ‘country’ choices list
        self.fields["country"].queryset = Country.objects.filter(active=True)

    def set_labels(self):
        """Override field labels here."""
        pass

    def set_required_values(self):
        """Make specific fields mandatory here."""
        pass

    def set_initial_values(self):
        """Set initial field values here."""
        pass
```

If the `ChoiceField` is the only thing you're going to be customising, this is all you need:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('country', 'contact_phone', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # only show active countries in the ‘country’ choices list
        self.fields["country"].queryset = Country.objects.filter(active=True)
```

You can then make your FormView use this form with like this:

```
class ProfileFormView(FormView):
    template_name = "profile.html"
    form_class = ProfileForm
```